# Want to know the usage of geocoding-api key of limit $300

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

I have activated free Google cloud account giving me access to the google-geocoding-api key of limit up to $300.

How do I know that how much my application is accessing the api per day and how much is remaining?     Is there an option for displaying how much I have access the API over time or possibly a notification that will be sent to me.

I want to know about the calculation of key access per day and the daily usage limit. From where I can see these details.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You should get an email every month starting how much you have used that month and what you are being billed.

you can also check your Google developers console and see the current status of your billing account.

[image]

If you check the quote section you will find details on what calls you have made to the API and their response codes

Comment: Would -1s care to comment?   this is a valid developers question.   I answered before it was placed on hold it will likely help the author